# Manually add element to end of fetch array

Tags: php, arrays

i could not find anywhere an answer for this, and i am currently out of ideas.

I have the following loop which is made to store in an array, the resource of a database fetch

```
    $posts = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $posts[] = $row;
      }

          return $posts;
```

`var_dump` on `$posts` outputs the following:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'items' => string '16' (length=2)
          'item_name' => string 'Blu-ray Disc Player BDP-S1100' (length=29)
          'item_price' => string '3500.00' (length=7)
          'avatar' => string 'gallery/miniaturas/cf6772a2c2b72d575f11b41aee5a2f47.png' (length=55)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'items' => string '16' (length=2)
          'item_name' => string 'Blu-ray Disc Player BDP-S1100' (length=29)
          'item_price' => string '3500.00' (length=7)
          'avatar' => string 'gallery/miniaturas/a6bf82f38d930567a759eaef91d6fb30.png' (length=55)
```

What i wanna do is add one (1) static value with the key "type" and value "1" to the end of every array, so the `var_dump` will look like this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'items' => string '16' (length=2)
          'item_name' => string 'Blu-ray Disc Player BDP-S1100' (length=29)
          'item_price' => string '3500.00' (length=7)
          'avatar' => string 'gallery/miniaturas/cf6772a2c2b72d575f11b41aee5a2f47.png'
          'type' => int 1
   (length=55)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'items' => string '16' (length=2)
          'item_name' => string 'Blu-ray Disc Player BDP-S1100' (length=29)
          'item_price' => string '3500.00' (length=7)
          'avatar' => string 'gallery/miniaturas/a6bf82f38d930567a759eaef91d6fb30.png'
          'type' => int 1
   (length=55)
```

Is it possible? and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify `$row` before you append it. Avoids any extra overhead

```
$posts = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $row['type'] = 1;
      $posts[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add an arbitrary key to the array with the value 1 like this:

```
$posts = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $posts[] = $row;
      $posts[count($posts)-1]["type"] = 1;
}

return $posts;
```

Alternatively, if you can edit your SQL query, you can also add `1 as type` to the end of your select and then your database will add the extra column for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but @Machavity one was more accurate so i chossed it. however this also does the job.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $posts[] = array_merge($row, array(
        'type' => 1,
    ));
}
```

Or, alternatively, modify your SQL query to automatically add the field:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, 1 AS type FROM table';
```